# ¿Cómo funciona la comparación "\>" y "\<" en Bash? ¿Cuándo puede ser útil?

Tags: string, bash, script, comparaciones

Estuve comparando textos usando los operadores `\<` y `\>` dentro de un if pero me eh encontrado con:

```
a="mica"
b="lorita"
if [ "$a" \> "$b" ]; then
    echo "$a es MAYOR que $b"
fi

if [ "$a" \< "$b" ]; then
    echo "$a es MENOR que $b"
fi
```

El output que me da esto es:

`mica es MAYOR que lorita`

Pero no entiendo por qué. ¿Cómo funciona este tipo de comparacion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Con `\<` y `\>`, lo que estás haciendo es una comparación lexicográfica. Esto es, una comparación por caracteres y que se basa en que "a" es más pequeña que "b" y así seguido:

```
$ [ "a" \< "b" ] && echo "si"
si
$ [ "A" \< "b" ] && echo "si"
si
$ [ "c" \< "b" ] && echo "si" || echo "no"
no
```

"A" también es más pequeña que "b", por lo que la forma de pensarlo es que está ordenando alfabéticamente.

¿Para qué puede ser útil esto? Pues por ejemplo para ver el orden de los nombres o apellidos de una serie:

```
$ [ "juan" \< "pedro" ] && echo "si"
si
```

Que es precisamente lo que viste en tu ejemplo: "mica" se considera mayor que "lorita" porque la primera empieza por "m" que es lexicográficamente mayor que "l".

Comment: Excelente respuesta